# How to change Cordova application icon?

Tags: cordova

I designed an icon in `4` standard sizes : `hdpi`, `ldpi`, `mdpi` and `xhdpi`.

I put these icons into :

- `"\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi"`
- `"\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi"`
- `"\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi"`
- `"\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi"` folder.

The names of each icon is `"icon.jpg"`.

How can I use these icons as my application icon?

Comment: See the official docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens The folder they use in the example is `res/android/` this `res` folder lives in the project root (where your www folder, hooks etc. live.)  The file will be automatically renamed for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer may vary based on your version of Cordova, but as of Cordova 3.5.0, this is the way of adding icons to your project. As mentioned in my comment, see the [official docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) for the source.

First create a folder for your icons to live. This will vary depending on your platform, since we are dealing with Android in your case, an `assets` folder will do nicely. It is easiest to create this in the project root (i.e. with the `www/` `hooks/` folders, `config.xml` file etc.)

While this won't impact you, it might be good to note. There is a small BlackBerry quirk regarding icons and splash screens. For BB10 you must place your assets folder in the `www/` directory.

Drop your icons in there and add something along these lines to your `config.xml` file, where the pngs correspond to your icons:

```
<platform name="android">    
    <icon src="assets/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="assets/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="assets/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="assets/xdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="assets/xxdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Lastly, you can verify these worked after your build by checking the `platforms\android\res\drawable-` folders.  They will contain an `icon.png` file that was copied across from your source directory during the build.

Answer (score 4):

Add a folder res in app and create folder in it icons/android and save images there

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

put your logo file named `logo.png` inside `www/img` dir

On `config.xml` file add:

```xml
<icon src="www/img/logo.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<platform name="android">


<icon src="icon.png" platform="ios" width="147" height="147" density="mdpi"/>     



</platform>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.